# Installing enaml in Anaconda

Tags: python, c++, installation, atom-editor, enaml

I am trying to install enaml for the latest Anaconda distribution(4.3.1). The installation guide on http://nucleic.github.io/enaml/docs/get_started/installation.html says:

> The sections below describe how to install Enaml and all of its dependencies from scratch, starting with the installation of a Python runtime. The instructions assume that the user’s system has a C++ compiler and the Git command line tools installed and available on the system path.
>
> The Easy Way
>
> If installing and building Enaml and its dependencies from scratch is not appealing, the free (and unaffiliated) Anaconda Python distribution provides a complete Python environment which comes with a reasonably recent version of Enaml and a host of other useful packages.
>
> If you have a working C++ compiler, you can install using pip:
>
> $ pip install enaml

**Can you please tell me the easiest way to install a C++ compiler and Git command line tools and make them available on system path?**

What I tried:
I tried installing Visual Studio however it turns out to be 32 bit so when pip installing enaml or atom I get the following error:

Failed building wheel for atom

fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and run `pip install enaml` again. There's also a tutorial here [Python GUI's with enaml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMjiPRSWFdY&t=2s) that shows how to get started from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install enaml` is the more idiomatic way to install packages in anaconda than `pip install`, at least for packages it knows about. Enaml and Atom are among this list.

This bypasses C++ compilation so it may not be what you want, but it is the easiest way to install Enaml. (I have a black thumb when it comes to building from source, so Anaconda works very well for me.)